# Converting currency for stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, currency

I am using stripe for a freelance marketplace. When sending an invoice to a client the amount is in US dollars.

When a client from Australia pays for the invoice it charges them AUD instead of USD.

I understand you can't charge them in USD.

Does anyone know how I can convert the amount into the origin currency, before charging the client.

For example, if the invoice amount is $400 USD, how can I convert the amount in AUD to get the $400 USD?

Comment: which language you working with ?

Comment: You have to make a conversion. [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#currency-conversions) is the official doc for this situation

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can charge them in USD - [`currency` is a required parameter in creating a Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-currency) - but you won't know how much AUD they'll be charged by their bank/card issuer, so you'll [need to estimate that](https://stripe.com/docs/payouts/conversions#calculating-foreign-exchange-rates).

Comment: Okay thanks. Would you happen to know if there are any good php packges for currency conversion?

Comment: I don't - and I'm not sure one exists - but you really just need to pick a currency conversion API and then make requests to that; it's possible they'll have an SDK/library.

Comment: It’s typically a bad idea to tell your customers how much they will pay in their local currency when you charge them in a different currency. If they end up paying more than you suggested, they have every right to come after you for the difference. IANAL, but you can mitigate this with a well-worded disclaimer.